# "Shipping and Billing address are the same " / Need to copy current shipping address to billing address - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

[image: When shipping address and billing address are the same , I need to copy my current shipping address to the billing address , not the default case .]

Which function checks shipping address and billing address are the same ? and where it copies the billing address to the shipping address ? Need to replace the default method. Instead need to copy current billing address to shipping address

Comment: Check out this file - /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js

Comment: Hello @Arun have found the solution for above?

Comment: Hi @Aaditya , am trying to customize the code and trying to change the function .Beginner in magento can you help how i can customize this section ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Happy to help!

Comment: Hello @Arun Have you tried that function and the url - https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/ to customize one page checkout ?

Comment: hi @Aaditya , I have changed the data for the function "setCustomerAddressData" , but its not changing billing address . I need to copy current shipping address as billing address

Answer (score 0):

> Which function checks shipping address and billing address are the
>   same ? and where it copies the billing address to the shipping address
>   ?

**Magento's default function for check same address**

> /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php

```
public function getSameAsBilling()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SAME_AS_BILLING);
    }
```

**Magento uses this function in OneStep Checkout page**

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

```
if (!$shipping->getSameAsBilling()) {
    $customerShippingData = $shipping->exportCustomerAddress();
    $customerShippingData->setIsDefaultShipping(true);
    $shipping->setCustomerAddressData($customerShippingData);
    // Add shipping address to quote since customer Data Object does not hold address information
    $quote->addCustomerAddress($customerShippingData);
} else {
    $shipping->setCustomerAddressData($customerBillingData);
    $customerBillingData->setIsDefaultShipping(true);
}
```